# Expose a binary to other Android apps

Tags: android, apk

I wanted to have `git` available as a CLI tool on my android device, usable via a local terminal app. I've successfully cross-compiled `git` for `aarch64-linux-android` and if I use a root shell to move it to one of the `ext4` filesystems on the device I can invoke it successfully.

However, installing and using it with root is not desirable. I normally leave my device unrooted and only temporarily enable root to do experiments like this. Installation as root is not so bad, but it seems that the only `ext4` filesystems mounted read/write are in locations that the terminal app cannot read from, so I cannot use it as a non-root user, which is a deal breaker *.

I'd prefer to package it as an APK if possible, so it can be sideloaded as a normal user. I'd also like to be able to invoke it from the terminal app. If I have to manually adjust `$PATH`, that's fine, but bonus points if the APK can place it somewhere on `$PATH` or have the OS extend `$PATH` on installation.

* *(I know I can remount /system as r/w to install it as root, and that would make it usable to all applications. I don't want to modify /system because then "factory resets" are not ensured to bring me back to a working state. I know it'd be a relatively safe change. If this really is impossible, I'll do that, but an APK would be so much nicer)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this. Android is designed to prevent such things: each APK can only run in a (somewhat) isolated container.

An APK cannot install an executable in the root folders. Modifying `$PATH` will also not work (if the system would even allow you to modify it) because each APK is executed by a different user, thus the environment will be different. I'm not even sure you can mark a file as executable on common folders.

One workaround to this would be to make the path of the executable (if you can mark a file as executable, that is) available through a `ContentResolver`.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I was hoping for some ability to say "this APK depends on this other APK" to get some sort of docker-like union of the available resources. Or a "expose these resources to the rest of the OS via a namespace" or something.  I guess I could publish a "root-only" APK which just copies the binaries into `/system`.

Comment: Yes, that's how this kind of features are used usually.